# Photo swipe gallery with preview

Tags: iphone, ipad

Is there any good example or piece of code for an iphad photo gallery app? Something like displaying the current picture and a bar at the bottom with all clickable thumbs as preview?

Would be great to see how this is done.

best

stefan